# Move the currency from one cell to another

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Let's say that in my cell `A1` I have the amount 2'000. And I used the format so that it writes me $2000.

How could I write a formula that would write in `B1`: $

So only keep the currency in `B1`.

Because when I use `=LEFT(A1;1)`, it will find "2" as the first value of the list (as the currency has been added changing the format of the cell)

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test for the currency format like this:
`=IF(LEFT(CELL("format",A1),1)="C","$","not currency")`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I am working on it, but I only have one problem, I have excel in french, and I don't think that C sends me to the same category. Do you have an idea where I could find this list in french so I can see what is the function letter ?

Comment: You could find the list in the help content of the function. In the french version, currency seems to be `P2` in the most cases. You could also try to check `C0`, `M0`, `M2`, `M2-`. Note that you could try to use the formula `=CELLULE("format"; A1)` in another cell to check the value returned

Comment: Btw, please consider commiting into [Stackoverflow in french](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12692/stack-overflow-in-french?referrer=fzGo7jeXaHzZeiYutxUqXw2) where this kind of question would be easier to answer without *internationalizing* the formula

Comment: @Jmax Thanks for that comment - i wouldn't have expected the labeling to change for another language

Comment: You're welcome. Me neither :). IMHO, that's quite weird... (note that I've checked on a french version of Excel 2007

Comment: Perfect, thank you brett and thank you JMax. Max I already have an account on french stackoverflow, but usually I work on both version of excels, so I like knowing both, this is why :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a helper UDF (alt+f11, insert->module) and add

```
public function DISPLAY_TEXT(cell as range) as string
   '//get display value as a string 
   DISPLAY_TEXT = cell.text
end function
```

Would allow you to:

```
=LEFT(DISPLAY_TEXT(A1),1)
```